# How do I improve this for loop in python, maybe numpy arrays?

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop

This code works but is too slow, any ideas for improvement would be appreciated.
Numpy arrays?, other?

```
Estatus=Vigentes[['UUID','Estatus']]
MOV_10 = MOV_09.copy()
MOV_10['Estatus'] = ""
for i in range(0, len(MOV_10[['UUID']])):
    u = MOV_10.loc[i][0]
    w = MOV_10.loc[i][1]
    tempu = Estatus.loc[Estatus['UUID'] == u]
    tempw = Estatus.loc[Estatus['UUID'] == w]
    try:
        if w == 'N/A':
            MOV_10.loc[i, 'Estatus'] = int(tempu.iloc[0, 1])
        else:
            MOV_10.loc[i, 'Estatus'] = int(tempu.iloc[0, 1]) \
                * int(tempw.iloc[0, 1])
    except IndexError:
        MOV_10.loc[i, 'Estatus'] = 0
```

#Estatus table, Mov_09 Table, Mov_10 Table, expected result

|  | UUID | Estatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 0 |
| 1 | b | 1 |
| 2 | x | 1 |
| 3 | y | 1 |

|  | UUID | UIID_2 | estatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | x |  |
| 1 | b | y |  |

|  | UUID | UIID_2 | estatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | x | 0*1 |
| 1 | b | y | 1*1 |

Comment: Can you please explain what the code does? You can also put there sample input (small) and expected output.

Comment: Well basically looks up for the status of a document  in a table, there are documents in MOV_10 in column "UUID"(Estatus.loc[Estatus['UUID']), we need to know the status of the document (eithe 0 or 1), the problem is the document as a relation with another document (MOV_10.loc[i][1]), so whenever either is zero the estatus should be 0

Comment: How is your original data stored? Given the code it looks like pandas data frames?

Comment: Hello, yes panda data frames, they come from a huge CVS files, the code works, but it takes a lot of processing time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do much better than your existing method. I assume your existing data structure is a pandas dataframe. If so, it's very straightforward swap to use vector operations for a lot of the calculations. This approach should also scale much better than your approach.

```
uuid_index = Estatus.set_index('UUID').rename(columns={'Estatus': 'val'})
out = pd.DataFrame({ 'UUID': MOV_09.UUID.values, 'UIID2': MOV_09.UIID2.values }).join(uuid_index, on=['UUID']).join(uuid_index, on=['UIID2'], rsuffix='_uiid2')
out['Estatus'] = 0
out.loc[out.val_uiid2 != 0, 'Estatus'] = out.val / out.val_uiid2
```

using this approach gives the following performance improvement for a dataset of with 1000 entries in the MOV_09 table:

| Method | Time | Relative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Original | 8.066573400050402 | 193.82507958031653 |
| Swapping to joining dataframes | 0.04161780001595616 | 1.0 |

I have attached the test code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import timeit

# generate test data
random.seed(1)
iterations = 10
uuid_count = 1000
mov_count = 1000

uuid_values = [(hex(i), random.random(), random.randint(0, 1)) for i in range(uuid_count)]
uuid_values.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

def rand_uuid():
    return uuid_values[random.randint(0, uuid_count - 1)][0]

mov_values = set()
for i in range(mov_count):
    uuid = rand_uuid()
    while not ((uiid2 := rand_uuid()) and not (pair := (uuid, uiid2)) in mov_values): pass
    mov_values.add(pair)

Estatus = pd.DataFrame({
    'UUID': [v[0] for v in uuid_values],
    'Estatus': [v[2] for v in uuid_values],
})

MOV_09 = pd.DataFrame({
    'UUID': [t[0] for t in mov_values],
    'UIID2': [t[1] for t in mov_values],
})

# base method
def method0():
    MOV_10 = MOV_09.copy()
    MOV_10['Estatus'] = ""
    for i in range(0, len(MOV_10[['UUID']])):
        u = MOV_10.loc[i][0]
        w = MOV_10.loc[i][1]
        tempu = Estatus.loc[Estatus['UUID'] == u]
        tempw = Estatus.loc[Estatus['UUID'] == w]
        try:
            if w == 'N/A':
                MOV_10.loc[i, 'Estatus'] = int(tempu.iloc[0, 1])
            else:
                MOV_10.loc[i, 'Estatus'] = int(tempu.iloc[0, 1]) \
                    * int(tempw.iloc[0, 1])
        except IndexError:
            MOV_10.loc[i, 'Estatus'] = 0
    return MOV_10

# updated method
def method1():
    uuid_index = Estatus.set_index('UUID').rename(columns={'Estatus': 'val'})
    out = pd.DataFrame({ 'UUID': MOV_09.UUID.values, 'UIID2': MOV_09.UIID2.values }).join(uuid_index, on=['UUID']).join(uuid_index, on=['UIID2'], rsuffix='_uiid2')
    out['Estatus'] = 0
    out.loc[out.val_uiid2 != 0, 'Estatus'] = out.val / out.val_uiid2
    return out[['UUID', 'UIID2', 'Estatus']]

m0 = method0()
m0['Estatus'] = m0.Estatus.astype(np.int64)
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(m0, method1())

t0 = timeit.timeit(lambda: method0(), number=iterations)
t1 = timeit.timeit(lambda: method1(), number=iterations)

tmin = min((t0, t1))

print(f'| Method                                  | Time | Relative      |')
print(f'|------------------                       |----------------------|')
print(f'| Original                                | {t0} | {t0 / tmin}   |')
print(f'| Swap to joining dataframes              | {t1} | {t1 / tmin}   |')
```

Comment: Wow, I just tried it (with minor modifications) and there is no comparison, thank you, you are amazing.

Comment: I think for loops are incredibly inefficient

Comment: I think the major is using vectorised calls. Pandas is built on top of numpy which is a c library. A calculation like `out.val / out.val_uiid2` is done as one operation in numpy, whereas the previous for loop calls in and out of numpy lots of times.

Comment: Performing vector operations on arrays in numpy also benefits from processor predictive caching (your CPU expects you to use adjacent memory looking forward and preloads it; you potentially lose this benefit if you access the data piecemeal). The are various processor caches (L1/L2/L3, for example 1.125MB/18MB/24.74MB on an i9-9980XE) and if your code uses data already in these caches it will be much much faster; caching strategies for array operations are designed around this and popping in and out of python is likely to interrupt the flow.

Comment: I get rid off of all my for loops, I went from "Time for code to run:  1585.741354227066" to "Time for code to run:  145.9215841293335"